# Close <div> When I've Tabbed out of It

Tags: javascript, keyboard, accessibility, keyboard-events

I have a panel with a list that gets opened on a button click:

```
<button id="menuButton">Menu</button>
<div id="menuPanel">
    <ul>
        <li>Name</li>
        <li>Role</li>
        <li>Profile</li>
        <li>Management</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The button click uses JavaScript to add a CSS class to the  to display it. For keyboard users, I want to be able to remove that class if they tab past the last element in the .

**JavaScript:**

```
(function ready(fn) {
    if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === 'complete' : document.readyState !== 'loading') {
        fn();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);

        let panel = document.getElementById('menuPanel'),
            button = document.getElementById('menuButton');

        button.onclick = checkPanelOn;

        function checkPanelOn(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            if (panel.classList.contains('on')) {
                panel.classList.remove('on');
            } else {
                panel.classList.add('on');
            }
        }
    }
}());
```

I'm looking for a pure JavaScript solution (sorry, can't use jQuery on this project) but I'm struggling to find an answer. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Post the full code please :-) You'd use the focus effect, but I'd need the full code to actually help

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy done, and thanks.

Comment: so if I understand correctly, when users click `TAB` they will be able to go trough  the list right? and once they are in the last element of the list the dropdown will remove the `class=on`?

Comment: @JoseCC correct. They tab through the list, and if they tab past the last item, I'd like to remove the class.

Comment: hiding the menu when you tab off the last element is a great feature.  you should be able to do that with an `onblur()` event handler.  you should also hide the menu if ESC is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it using `tabindex` and `focusout` :

```js
let panel = document.getElementById('menuPanel'),
  button = document.getElementById('menuButton');

button.onclick = checkPanelOn;

panel.addEventListener('focusout', function(event) {
  if (panel.contains(event.relatedTarget)) {
    return;
  }
  checkPanelOn(event);
});

function checkPanelOn(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  if (panel.classList.contains('on')) {
    panel.classList.remove('on');
  } else {
    panel.classList.add('on');
  }
}
```

```css
.on {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="menuButton">Menu</button>
<div id="menuPanel">
  <ul>
    <li tabindex="0">Name</li>
    <li tabindex="0">Role</li>
    <li tabindex="0">Profile</li>
    <li tabindex="0">Management</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button>Outside button</button>
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nzmtL1od/

Comment: the OP had the `accessibility` tag on their question.  because of this, `tabindex` values greater than 0 should absolutely not be used.  it creates a terrible experience for keyboard users.  see the warning in the html spec for tabindex - https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/editing.html#the-tabindex-attribute

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy thanks for the demo. In my example, I need to preserve accessibility for keyboard users. Setting the tabindex is something that will impact the rest of the page. Is there a way to do this without setting the tabindex on any element?

Comment: @MattSmith you can't tab into an `li` without a `tabindex`, but what you could do is to set `tabindex="0"` which makes an element "tabbable" without affecting page flow.

Comment: @slugolicious in that same logic, I edited my answer to have `tabindex="0"` so it would work while at the same time not affect the whole page. Kindly go once again over your downvote :-)

Comment: still an accessibility issue.  non-interactive elements (such as list items) should **not** receive keyboard focus.  if the list items were links, or performed some action, then it would be ok.  but if the list item performed an action, it would need a `role` so that screen readers understand what the list item is doing.  i think the problem goes back to the OP and perhaps they need a better explanation of what they're doing.  if they are creating a menu, then the keyboard interactions are well defined at https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-11.

Comment: i'll undo the downvote but i would still not use this answer to solve the problem as it still has accessibility problems.